# Pause execution until file is saved

Tags: vbscript

Using vbscript I want to be able to create an excel object, allow the user to open a file then  after they save it, be able to verify the data in the file. I have tried using WaitForChangedResult to watch the directory where the file is and wait for it to change before proceeding, however it only moves on when the file is closed without saving, not when its saved. here's what that code looks like:

```
Dim xl As Object
xl = CreateObject("excel.application")
xl.FileDialog(1).AllowMultiSelect = False
xl.FileDialog(1).Title = "Navigate to 60-40 loan calculator"
Dim strFilePathAndName As String
If xl.FileDialog(1).Show() = -1 Then
    strFilePathAndName = xl.FileDialog(3).SelectedItems(1)
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
xl.Visible = True
xl.Workbooks.Open(strFilePathAndName)
Dim strXLTab As String
strXLTab = xl.ActiveSheet.Name


Dim result As System.IO.WaitForChangedResult
Dim directory As String
directory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
Dim watcher As New System.IO.FileSystemWatcher(directory, "Calculator.xls")
result = watcher.WaitForChanged(System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Changed)
TextBox1.Text = directory
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to monitor a file for changes.

Just substitute your code in the place of the Wscript.echo commands to take the action that you need to when the file is changed / created / deleted.

```
' Monitors a file for modifications.
Dim intTimer:        intTimer = "2"
Dim strDrive:        strDrive = "c:"
Dim strPath:         strPath = "\\temp\\"
Dim strFile:         strFile = "log.txt"
Dim strComputer:     strComputer = "."
Dim objWMIService:   Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts:" &  "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2" )
Dim strQuery:        strQuery = "Select * From __InstanceOperationEvent" & " Within " & intTimer & " Where Targetinstance Isa 'CIM_DataFile'" & " And TargetInstance.Drive='" & strDrive & "'" & " And TargetInstance.Path='" & strPath & "'"
Dim colEvents:       Set colEvents = objWMIService. ExecNotificationQuery (strQuery)
WScript.Echo "Monitoring file changes... Press [Ctrl]-[C] to exit"
Do
    Set objEvent = colEvents.NextEvent()
    Set objTargetInst = objEvent.TargetInstance
    if right(objTargetInst.Name,len(strFile)) = strFile then
        Select Case objEvent.Path_.Class
            Case "__InstanceCreationEvent"
                WScript.Echo "Created: " & objTargetInst.Name
            Case "__InstanceDeletionEvent"
                WScript.Echo "Deleted: " & objTargetInst.Name
            Case "__InstanceModificationEvent"
                WScript.Echo "Modified: " & objTargetInst.Name
        End Select
    end if
Loop
```

Run this with **Wscript** and it is not visible or run it with **Cscript** to make it visible in a console window.